# Где сказуемое, а где подлежащее?

Tags: синтаксис

```
Учиться - вот наша задача.
я так понимаю, что задача - подлежащие, а учиться сказуемое.
В учебнике пишут наоборот, не могу понять почему? 
2) почему в предложении : Моя сестра учительница. тире не ставится? Хотя здесь явно сказуемое выражено подлежащим!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо перестроить предложение: Учиться является нашей задачей. Форма подлежащего не изменяется, форма сказуемого меняется.

Славное место эта долина! Перестроим: Эта долина является славным местом. Долина - подлежащее.

Примечание.

Тире не ставится, даже если сказуемое выражено сущ. в им. падеже, лишь в речи разговорной, бытовой:

Мы с мужем люди небогатые, но образованные (М. Г.);

В письменной речи отражено произношение с логическим ударением на сказуемом:

Моя сестра учительница (ср.: Моя сестра — учительница — ударение и на слове сестра, и на слове учительница).

Тире обязательно: 1) если имеется сопоставление: Моя сестра — учительница, а брат — зоотехник; 
2) если возможна синтаксическая или смысловая двусмысленность; ср.: Брат — мой учитель и Брат мой — учитель.

Answer (score 1):

*Моя сестра учительница*.  Тире не ставится в простых по структуре предложениях. Хотя интонационное тире Вы вполне можете поставить. Но это правило не основное. Если Вы ученик, то в диктантах рекомендую тире ставить. Далеко не все учителя об этом дополнении к основному правилу знают.

*Учиться - вот наша задача.* О чем говорится в предложении? О том, что учиться - это задача. Учебник  прав. Учиться - подлежащее, задача - сказуемое. *Наша задача - учиться.* Предмет речи поменялся. Говорится о том, что задача - это... Теперь задача - подлежащее, учиться - сказуемое.

Comment: 1. Что такое "простые по структуре" предложения? "Москва - столица нашей Родины" - простое "по структуре"?

2. "Москва - столица" - точно простое. Тогда тире - не нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Между подлежащим и сказуемым ставится тире, если то и другое выражено сущ. в им. пад., инфинитивом; подлежащее может быть выражено инфинитивом, а сказуемое -  сущ. в им. пад. и наоборот. Поэтому в нашем случае подлежащее - учиться (в значении "учёба").